# creating dynamic playlist by reading songs from a table using jquery for the jPlayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer, playlist

i am using the JPlayer for a website.
Now, i want to create playlist from a table with path and artist names.
Now what i did is i added the table to the page and now, using forEach i tried to
read the path and add it to the playlist. but somehow i am confused.. 
Have a look
this is the code i used for grabbing path and it works fine

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#songsPathGridView tr').each(function () {
            if (!this.rowIndex) return; // skip first row
            var path = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
            alert(path);

        });
    });
</script>
```

and now this is the playlist that i have (hard coded values). Now if it was in html or something i could have appended that path to it but since it's jquery code please tell me how to do it..
here is the playlist code

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var songName = "Song1";
        var theArtist = "The Artist";
        var myPlaylist = [
            {
                mp3: 'music/Mad.mp3', oga: 'mix/1.ogg', title: songName, artist: theArtist,
            },
          {
              mp3: 'mix/EssentialViolet.mp3', oga: 'mix/2.ogg', title: songName, artist: theArtist, cover: 'mix/2.jpg'
          }
        ];
        $('body').ttwMusicPlayer(myPlaylist, {
            autoPlay: false,

            jPlayer: {
                swfPath: '../plugin/jquery-jplayer' //You need to override the default swf path any time the directory structure changes
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Somehow i wanna get the filepath and add it dynamically. Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to see the HTML code you're using for the table, because it will impact the construction, but essentially this method should work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var myPlaylist = [{}]; // Empty object to push into

    $('#songsPathGridView tr').each(function () {
        if (!this.rowIndex) return; // skip first row
        // Push each row's data into the myPlaylist variable
        // Expects MP3 path at column 0, title at column 1, artist at column 2
        myPlaylist.push( { mp3: this.cells[0].innerHTML, title: this.cells[1].innerHTML, artist: this.cells[2].innerHTML } );
    });

    $('body').ttwMusicPlayer(myPlaylist, {
        autoPlay: false,
        jPlayer: {
            swfPath: '../plugin/jquery-jplayer' //You need to override the default swf path any time the directory structure changes
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: There is no html code for this, the markup is done dynamically  and only the table ive put up for the table path. let me try your code and ill let you know.

Comment: OK, if the table has just one column (for paths) you may want to remove the code `, title: this.cells[1].innerHTML, artist: this.cells[2].innerHTML` because it expects 2 additional columns in the table to populate the artist and song title values.

Comment: Wow it worked, thanks a Million man, just one more Question i have a second table with name of the Artist, how can i append that to this playlist. i mean artist name from another table to these songs?

Comment: Woop,s there seems a problem, the song runs fine now on first click but hen i click another song and come back to same song it dosen't play :(

Comment: Yeah works fine now,but please tell me how to append Artist too:)

Comment: Great! Can you send me a link to the page where I can see the tables? It should be very easy to pull in artist, but hard to know without seeing the table structure.

Comment: Its woeking fine now but it seems like it's adding a dummy song on first place.. I mean a blank LI is added at the first record.. is it reading from the table headers, the alert says it only reads the songs path but somehow, a blank li is also added on first number?? Please help man.

Comment: Try changing this line `if (!this.rowIndex) return; // skip first row` to this: `if (this.rowIndex < 1) return; // skip first row`